# Unable to store or append values into list while multiprocess in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Please correct me if any wrong.

```
import multiprocess
  
#reading the text from pdf
failed_files=[]
def get_text_pdfs(filename):
         .....
         .....
         coll=[]
         if(len(coll)==15):
            insert_into_db()
         else:
            # Global failed_files
            failed_files.append(filename)
#grabing_pdfs_from_directory
list_of_pdfs=get_pdfs_list(path)
if(list_of_pdfs!=None):
    p=Pool(5)
    p.map(get_text_pdfs,list_of_pdfs)
print(failed_files)
```

Comment: You need to provide a code in your original post.

Comment: import multiprocess 
#reading the text from pdf
failed_files=[]
def get_text_pdfs(filename):
     .....
     .....
     coll=[]
     if(len(coll)==15):
        insert_into_db()
     else:
      Global failed_files
    failed_files.append(filename)


#grabing_pdfs_from_directory
list_of_pdfs=get_pdfs_list(path)


if(list_of_pdfs!=None):
 p=Pool(5)
 p.map(get_text_pdfs,list_of_pdfs)
print(failed_files)

Comment: you need to use `multprocess.Manager` to share the list among all the processes.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most efficient solution is to have your worker function `get_text_pdfs` return `None` if there is no error else `filename`. The main process can then build the `failed_files` list from the return values that are not `None`:

```py
import multiprocessing
  
def get_text_pdfs(filename):
    ...
    coll=[]
    if(len(coll)==15):
       insert_into_db()
       return None # No error
    else:
       # Global failed_files
       return filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #grabing_pdfs_from_directory
    list_of_pdfs = get_pdfs_list(path)
    # This checks for a non-empty list:
    if list_of_pdfs:
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
        failed_files = [
            filename for filename in p.map(get_text_pdfs, list_of_pdfs)
                if filename is not None
        ]
        p.close()
        p.join()
    else:
        failed_files = []
    print(failed_files)
```

If you insist that `get_text_pdfs` do the appending, then the list must be sharable across processes and for that you need to use a *managed list* (but note that every operation on such a list is considerably more expensive compared to a standard list):

```py
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
  
def get_text_pdfs(failed_files, filename):
    ...
    coll=[]
    if(len(coll)==15):
       insert_into_db()
    else:
       # Global failed_files
       failed_files.append(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #grabing_pdfs_from_directory
    list_of_pdfs = get_pdfs_list(path)
    # This checks for a non-empty list:
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        failed_files = manager.list()
        if list_of_pdfs:
            p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
            p.map(partial(get_text_pdfs, failed_files), list_of_pdfs)
            p.close()
            p.join()
        print(failed_files)
```